# Automate response with read and expect in bash

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I want to automate the process when the user is prompted to enter his name, it should automatically write `world`.

```
#!/bin/bash

fullname=""
read -p "hello" fullname
/usr/bin/expect -c "expect hello {send world}"
echo $fullname
```

The code above still waits for user input to be entered. I want to get the behavior as below:

```
hello
world
```

Is it possible to achieve such behavior using `expect`? If yes, how?

**EDIT:** One would expect that `send world` would store its result in `fullname` variable. All the idea is to have `fullname` variable for later usage

Comment: Why not write the script all in expect.  It's basically Tcl if you know tcl your set.

Comment: Its still unclear exactly what you are asking here. Might be an example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Yes it unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Like why use expect at all? Why not just set `fullname` to `world`?

Comment: Well first reason is that I want to learn. And second reason, I plan to extend the code for other purposes. And I think the problem describes exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: It might be a good idea to get comfortable with bash, before you tackle expect. I left a link in my answer, but there are plenty on the web, read a few to find one that speaks to your level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `read -p "hello" fullname` is where your script pauses.
It will `read` the user input and assign it to `fullname`

The script below will achieve what you are asking for.

```
#!/bin/bash

fullname=$(echo hello | /usr/bin/expect -c  "expect hello {send world}")
echo "hello " $fullname
```

`expect` reads from stdin so we can use `echo` to send the data to it.

Then the output of expect is assigned to `fullname`.

Here is a link to a tutorial you might find useful. [Bash Prog Intro](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Answer (score 2):

Usually expect drives/automates other programs like ftp, telnet, ssh or bash even.  Using bash to drive an expect script is possible but not typical.  Here's an expect script that does what I think you want:

```
[plankton@localhost ~]$ cat hello.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_user 0
spawn read -p hello fn
expect {
        hello {
                send "world\r"
                expect {
                        world {
                                puts $expect_out(buffer)
                        }
                }
        }
}
[plankton@localhost ~]$ ./hello.exp
world
```

But as you can see its the long way round to just executing `puts world`.

In bash one could do this ...

```
$ read -p "hello" fullname <<EOT
> world
> EOT
$ echo $fullname
world
```

... but once again just the long way round for:

```
fullname=world
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need expect at all. To meet your requirements, all you need to do is:

```
echo world | /path/to/your/script
```

That will store "world" in the "fullname" variable.